# passing data to dynamically created ascx user control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to display user control which produces different set of data depending on values which are being passed to it.

No. of UserControls are decided at run-time

- Now it dint Hit in Page_Load of `ascx.cs`

**Default.aspx**

```
<%@ Register Src="~/UserControl/SquareEUA.ascx" TagName="Square" TagPrefix="EUA" %>

<body>
     <div id="divControls" runat="server"></div>
</body>
```

**Default.aspx.cs**

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    string[] Property;
    foreach (string sPropID in Property)
    {
SquareEUA userControl = (SquareEUA)Page.LoadControl("~/UserControl/SquareEUA.ascx"); 
        userControl.ID = "MyControl_" + sPropID.Trim();
        userControl.sCustID = CustomerID; 
        userControl.sCustPropID = sPropID.Trim(); 
        userControl.Visible = true;
        divControls.Controls.Add(userControl); 
        userControl.Dispose();
    }
    }
```

**SquareEUA.ascx**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="SquareEUA.ascx.cs" Inherits="UserControl.SquareEUA" %>
<div>
     // Some HTML Markup
</div>
```

**SquareEUA.ascx.cs**

```
public partial class SquareEUA : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
public string sCustID { get; set; }
public string sCustPropID { get; set; }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Some Code    
        // Didnt Hit Breakpoint Here;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to cast your usercontrol as the actual class SquareEUA to access that class's properties

```
SquareEUA userControl = (SquareEUA)(Page.LoadControl("~/UserControl/SquareEUA.ascx"));
```

that should do the trick (you should add some error handling, null check, etc.)

edit: seems I missed a parenthesis around (Page...

Comment: so can i access `userControl.sCustID` and set value in default.aspx.cs ?

Comment: No it gets HTML markup from UserControl. But why it didnt hit the breakpoint on `Page_Load` ?

Comment: if your break point on Page_Load does not work check if you have set AutoEventWireup="true" in your aspx / ascx

Comment: It is set true in `.ascx`